# Can't append a child to page from a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension, appendchild

This is the simplified code, it's stops working after the appendChild line:

```
$preview = {
    designImg: '',
    thePage: null,
    designPreviewer: null,
    init: function(){
        var divNode = $('<div>').attr('id','layoutVsDesign').html('test');
        document.body.appendChild( divNode );
        alert('I never happen');
        this.designPreviewer = document.body.find('#designPreviewer');
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $preview.init();
});
```

Any idea what I am missing?

I also tried:

```
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().appendChild()
```

With pretty much the same result

-EDIT-

Using [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html):

works (takes a string):

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
   code: 'document.body.style.display = "none"'
});
```

But

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
   code: 'document.body.appendChild("<div>tttttttesttt</div>")'
});
```

or

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
   code: 'document.body.appendChild(node[0])'
});
```

Won't work, how can I pass the node to the `code` parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the return value of `html` method to `divNode`

As you can find on [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/), `html` method used as a setter return the jQuery object to allow for chained calls.

So, you are trying to append a jQuery object to a DOM node, which is not valid.

What you have to do is:

```
var divNode = $('<div>').attr('id','layoutVsDesign').html('test');        
$("body").append( divNode ); //append a jQuery object using jQuery method
```

or otherwise:

```
var divNode = $('<div>').attr('id','layoutVsDesign').html('test');        
document.body.appendChild( divNode[0] ); //append a DOM node with DOM method
```

Comment: Hi there, this works, but its appending the node to the extension popup, I want to append it to the current page in chrome, is that posible?

Comment: I think you can do it using [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)

Comment: Hey! that's something, please check the edit on the question, thanks!

Comment: node[0] belong to your extension, not to the current page. You can do  
chrome.tabs.executeScript({ code: 'document.body.innerHTML+="<div/>"' })

Comment: use divNode.html() to get the html of your jQuery object as a string, and use it to build the code you inject in the page

Comment: Thanks! should `code: 'document.body.innerHTML += "<div id="layoutVsDesign">test</div>"'` work? not working for me...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46611/discussion-between-andrea-parodi-and-toni-michel-caubet)

Answer (score 1):

If the posted JS runs in a content script, you don't need the jQuery domload event. Content scripts are run usually when the dom has loaded. (You can change that in the manifest, but you shouldn't.)

Without jQuery, your `init()` would look like this:

```
// Create div
var divNode = document.createElement('div');
divNode.id = 'layoutVsDesign';
divNode.innerHTML = 'test';

// Append to open page doc
document.body.appendChild(divNode);

var thatDiv = document.querySelector('#layoutVsDesign');
alert(thatDiv);
this.designPreviewer = thatDiv;
```

You can run that `init()` at the bottom of the script, not inside an event handler.

If it runs as a content script, there's no need for background pages or `executeScript()`.

Your original code had a jQuery error btw: `document.body.find` wouldn't be a function.